# Realm Subquery in React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm new to realm.  I have a schema like the following:

```
class MealItem {}
MealItem.schema = {
    name: 'MealItem',
    properties: {
        mealId: {type: 'int'},
        foodId: {type: 'int'},
    },
};
```

I want to do the equivalent of :

```
SELECT
  mealId
FROM MealItem
WHERE foodId = @food1
AND mealId IN (SELECT mealId FROM MealItem WHERE foodId = @food2
AND mealId IN (SELECT mealId FROM MealItem WHERE foodId = @food3))
```

I'm not sure where to begin other than to write A LOT of javascript for loops.  Is there a less verbose way to do it?

**more info**

Basically I have two other objects like this:

```
class Meal {}
Meal.schema = {
    name: 'Meal',
    properties: {
        mealId: {type: 'int'},
        mealName: {type: 'string'},
    },
};
class Food{}
Food.schema = {
    name: 'Food',
    properties: {
        foodId: {type: 'int'},
        foodName: {type: 'string'},
    },
};
```

So my original query is meant to determine if given 3 different foods, does my restaurant offer a meal / combo for it.

For example, if you set food1 to **Big Mac**, food2 to **Fries**, food3 to **Soft Drink**, you should get a meal back called **Big Mac Meal**.

If you set food1 to **Durian**, food2 to **Hot Pockets**, food3 to **Krusty Brand Imitation Gruel**, no meal id will return, because my restaurant doesn't serve combo like that.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more to what you are achieving to have in the result of the query please?

Comment: @bennygenel ok just added more explanation to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about SQL but what I understand from your question is that you are trying to find meals that contains specific foods.

Realm queries and models works like a NoSQL database so you might need to think a little different while creating your models.

For example, lets say you have 3 tables. One contains Meals, one contains foods and one contains data about which `MealId` contains which `FoodId`. In Realm you don't need the 3 table. You can think as its a javascript object.

Example

```
const meal = {
  mealId: 0001,
  name: 'Big Fat Menu',
  price: '4.99'
  foods: [{
    foodId: 11,
    name: 'Burger'
  }, {
    foodId: 12,
    name: 'Fries'
  }, {
    foodId: 13,
    name: 'Coke'
  }]
}
```

This javascript object can be modeled with Realm like this

```
const FoodSchema = {
  name: 'Food',
  primaryKey: 'foodId',
  properties: {
    foodId: 'string'
    name: 'string',
  }
};

const MealsSchema = {
  name: 'Meal',
  primaryKey: 'mealId',
  properties: {
    mealId: 'string'
    name: 'string',
    price: 'double',
    foods: { type: 'list', , objectType: 'Food'}
  }
};
```

With this schema you can make following query to get a meal that contains a specific food,

```
const meals = realm..objects('Meal').filtered(`foods.id == ${foodId}`)
```

This is just a small example to help you out a bit. Hope it helps.

Comment: is `${foodId}` and array?  I'm referring to this statement `realm..objects('Meal').filtered(`foods.id == ${foodId}`)`.  Basically I want to only return meals if the three foods I pass it appear in the meal.

Comment: @John I didn't think it as an array while I was giving the example. `filtered` accepts use of `AND`. You can try `foods.id == ${foodId1} AND foods.id == ${foodId2} AND foods.id == ${foodId3}`. I'm not sure if this is gonna work because there is no documentation for it.